# What minimum android sdk version i need to use in manifest?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, mobile, air

Tech-specs said that 2.3 is mimum supported android
http://www.adobe.com/products/air/tech-specs.html

But next link
http://goo.gl/EikY1

"Note: The runtime requires a minimum SDK version greater than 8. You should ensure that the Manifest includes ."

And  android:minSdkVersion="8" is a Android 2.2.x
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

I download a lot of applications from google play and they have android:minSdkVersion="8" with 3.6 and above air vesrsion

Answer (score 0):

Like it says in the docs

> The runtime requires a minimum SDK version greater than 8. You should
>   ensure that the Manifest includes < uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8">

Comment: I ask this question because on android 2.2 occurs crashes when application play sound
http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1190829?tstart=0

And different info in specification and in documentation

Comment: well then its obviously a bug, and their onnit.

Answer (score 0):

I found you also need the `android:targetSdkVersion="29"` attribute as well.
`android:minSdkVersion` is not enough.